# How to color multi-row card by 'legend'?

Tags: powerbi

I want to color the padding (the vertical bar on the left) based on a column variable. Is this possible?

[image]

For example, for 'High' I want to color it red, 'Low' in green, etc.
This will ensure that the coloring is consistent across all graphics when I refer to this different level of the column (urgency).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there's no option to set color of vertical bar based on the value, but you can change the background color of the card based on the value of the card or custom metric.

[image: set background color]

Here Patric shows how to use field value to set format color programmatically https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgnPIaxpdJ0